# Evaluating integral by changing to polar coordinates: $\iint_D x^2y \;dA$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

> Evaluating integral by changing to polar coordinates $\iint_D x^2y \;dA$
> where $D$ is "the top half of the disk with center the
> origin and radius $5$."

I got:

$\iint_D (x^2y) dA$

$\int^\pi_0\int^5_0(rcos^2(\theta)r\sin(\theta))rdrd\theta$

$\int^\pi_0\int^5_0r^3(cos^2(\theta)\sin(\theta))drd\theta$

$\int^5_0 r^3(\cos^2(\theta)\sin(\theta))dr = \frac{625}{4}\cos^2(\theta)\sin(\theta)$

$\frac{625}{4}\int^{\pi}_0\cos^2(\theta)\sin(\theta)d\theta= \frac{625}{12}\cos(\theta)^3 |^\pi_0=\frac{-625}{12}-\frac{625}{12}=\frac{-625}{6}$

Using substitution with $u=\cos(\theta),$ and $ du=-\sin(\theta)d\theta$

But the book's answer says $\frac{-1250}{3}$.

Comment: Why polar-coordinates?

Comment: What is the domain of integration?

Comment: Also, from second to third line you should have $r^4$ not $r^2$.

Comment: Sorry, domain: "top half of the disk with center the
origin and radius 5" and polar coords because it said so.

Comment: Oh.. ok I see it with the r now. Fixing that and trying again.

Comment: Ok, post updated showing domain and what I have after fixing the power of r problem, which still didn't come out to the book answer.

Comment: Please read the comments.

Comment: On the third line it suppose to be $r^4$ instead of $r^3$.

Comment: Forgot to square the r when I converted the $x^2$... Ok. I get it. The first time I read the comments I just seen the second mistake of missing the third r after my initial mistake. Sorry, Jacky.

Comment: Ok, I see why I got that mixed up. I had problem earlier that was pulling the r out of cos PLUS sin problem and my brain just went and auto handled it the same way. Mentally flagged to watch for in the future.